# zero-init in gcc vs default-init in clang?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

I came across unexpected diffs between gcc and clang while value-initializing objects, and suspect a bug (or two).

1. Setup 1:

```cpp
struct A {
    A() {}
    int x;
};

struct B : A {
    int y;
};

int main() {
...
 B b {};  // How should b.x be initialized?
...
}
```

gcc makes `B b2 {}` zero-initialize A, and clang makes it default initialize (doesn't touch x): https://godbolt.org/z/8znhr41ro

Now for spelunking the standard to understand who is right. The value-initialization clause [says](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-9):

> 9 To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> (9.1) if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type ([class]), then
>
> (9.1.1) if T has either no default constructor ([class.default.ctor])
> or a default constructor that is user-provided or deleted, then the
> object is default-initialized;
>
> (9.1.2) otherwise, the object is zero-initialized and the semantic
> constraints for default-initialization are checked, and if T has a
> non-trivial default constructor, the object is default-initialized;
>
> (9.2) if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>
> (9.3) otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

While 9.1.2 is rather poorly phrased, I think the item relevant to this code is 9.3 - "the object is zero initialized".
The zero-initialization clause, [a few paragraphs prior](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-6), does define handling of base classes:

> 6 To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> (6.1) if T is a scalar type ([basic.types.general]), the object is
> initialized to the value obtained by converting the integer literal 0
> (zero) to T;
>
> (6.2) if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, its
> padding bits ([basic.types.general]) are initialized to zero bits and
> each non-static data member, each non-virtual base class subobject,
> and, if the object is not a base class subobject, each virtual base
> class subobject is zero-initialized;
>
> ...

So I think gcc is right here, and this is a clang bug. *

2. Setup 2 - comment out B's `int y` member:

```cpp
struct A {
    A() {}
    int x;
};

struct B : A {
//  int y;
};
```

This should have been the same to case 1, but gcc's behavior changes:  https://godbolt.org/z/Pvnh556de . Here both gcc and clang default-initialize (and not zero-initialize) A, and I suspect this  might be a bug in both.

Are any of these indeed bugs to report?  Or am I missing something?

---

- BTW I'm uneasy with the standard here. The user expressed their intent about what needs to happen when A is instantiated: "Do nothing". I'd say this intent should carry through to A's embedded as subobjects (members or bases). Zero-initializing A might even not make any sense.   But that's a different story that I'm happy to postpone to another occasion.

Comment: Which standard edition? (You didn't specify any flags in the link, but you are quoting the C++26 draft) Either way, trying to print an indeterminate value causes UB, so you can't use that to verify the behavior.

Comment: @user17732522  Standard version is irrelevant, these clauses are the same for at least as far back as c++17.   I used the dirty-stack hack just to check whether the compiler zeros `x` as I thought it should. Are you saying `x`'s value is *supposed to be* indeterminate and not zero?   How  so?

Comment: 9.3 doesn't apply here.  9.1 only branches to 9.1.1 or 9.1.2, those are the only things that happen during class initialization.  9.3 refers to if you don't have a class and you don't have an array

Comment: @NathanOliver You're right of course, thanks.  But which of the 9.1.1/9.1.2 branches apply? And if it is 9.1.2 - does it say to zero-init in this case?

Comment: Lol, GCC with `-Wall -O3` actually warns about `.x` being uninitialized, despite zeroing it: https://godbolt.org/z/dT8rjdeaz

Comment: @OfekShilon I believe 9.1.2 applies but it states *otherwise, the object is zero-initialized [...]* so you still get zero initialization, just not because of 9.3

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Maybe it is doing the user a favor by not causing a breaking behavior change between C++14 and C++17.

Comment: @user17732522 Looks unrelated to aggregateness. Making the base virtual doesn't change this.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat In that case then initialization to zero must happen (in both C++14 and C++17) and the warning would be a false-positive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will assume C++17 or later as per the comments in the question:

`B b {};` is syntactically *direct-list-initialization* by empty initializer list, *list-initialization* referring to the use of a braced initializer list. The rules for this are specified in [dcl.init.list].

`B` is an aggregate class (since C++17). As a consequence any list-initialization results semantically in *aggregate-initialization*, not *value-initialization*.

In contrast to initialization with empty parentheses which would be *value-initialization* (grammar ambiguity making it unusable as declaration initializer aside) and declaration without initializer which would be *default-initialization*.

Given that no aggregate element has any explicit initializer in the aggregate-initialization, each element is initialized as if by `= {}`, i.e. *copy-list-initialization* by an empty initializer list.

The consequence is that `B::y` is zero-initialized (as in `int y = {};`) which I won't go into detail on.

`A` is *not* an aggregate class because it has a user-provided constructor and therefore initialization with `= {}` falls through the in the list-initialization rules until [[dcl.init.list]/3.5](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#list-3.5) which states that the subobject will be *value-initialized*.

And per your quotes, because `A` *does* have a default constructor that is user-provided, the subobject is *default-initialized* by (9.1.1). To default-initialize a class type does not imply any zero-initialization, but only initialization by a call to the default constructor, which in your case doesn't initialize `B::A::x`.

So, `B::A::x` has an indeterminate value.

Removing the `B::y` member doesn't change anything about this. However, your approach to determining whether or not `x` has an indeterminate value is flawed. Trying to read an indeterminate `int` causes undefined behavior and the compiler doesn't have to provide any values consistent with what had been stored at the same memory location before.

So both compiler behave correctly in all cases.

---

Had you initialized with parentheses, e.g.

```
B b = B();
```

then the whole `B` object would have been *value-initialized* which would have implied *zero-initialization* of all of `B`, which recursively would have zero-initialized `B::A::x`. In that case all compilers would be required to print `0` in your test cases.

---

Regarding your last point: Even though the members will not be initialized per the above, it is unobservable to a program whether or not an initialization with zero happened regardless, since any attempt to read the value would be UB. Therefore a compiler is free to still do the zero-initialization regardless under the as-if rule.

---

Regarding previous C++ versions without going into too much detail:

In C++11 and C++14 zero-initialization of `x` is guaranteed with or without `y` because `B` isn't an aggregate class in C++14 and `{}` therefore causes *value-initialization* of the whole `B` object which means zero-initialization for lack of a user-provided/deleted constructor, which recursively implies zero-initialization of all subobjects, including `x`. (Per the value-initialization rules this is then still (usually) followed by a default constructor call that may replace the zero-initialization values.)

In C++98 and C++03 compilation will fail because `B` is not an aggregate class and therefore initialization with `{}` is not permitted syntax.

In C++98 and C++03 the rules for value-initialization are also different and wouldn't cause recursive zero-initialization anyway. This was however changed to the current behavior by [CWG 178](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/178.html) and [CWG 543](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/543.html) which [according to cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) should be considered defect reports against C++98 as well (I have no official reference on that).

Comment: `B` has a base class, and so is not an aggregate

Comment: @OfekShilon That's not the case since C++17. Base classes are allowed now for aggregate classes. This is why I asked you about the C++ edition.

Comment: Note specifying `-std=c++17` does not change the results: https://godbolt.org/z/YYcsno81s

Comment: @OfekShilon `-std=c++17` (or `-std=gnu++17`) is already the default for these compiler versions. However, if you chose `-std=c++14` instead you will see consistent zero-intialization, because then `B` isn't an aggregate anymore and it is indeed value-initialized with recursive zero-initialization. With `-std=c++17` the test cases have undefined behavior and the compiler can print whatever it wants, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: I had no idea that zero-initialization propagates even through user-provided constructors. I probably have a dozen answers that are wrong about this...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It was changed for C++03 I think or as a defect report shortly after. You can probably find it in the CWG defect report list by searching for zero-initialization or value-initialization. Should be linked on the cppreference page as well.

Comment: @user17732522 thanks! I didn't realize 'until c++17' in cppreference is non-inclusive.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Seems my interpretation was wrong. 9.1.2 is in effect, and it says "the object is zero-initialized and [... yadda yadda constraints yadda yadda, *and afterwards*...]  the object is default-initialized".  Outputting from `A::A()` shows this is indeed the case: https://godbolt.org/z/bM6qKKoYo

Comment: @OfekShilon 9.1.2 applies to `B` if it isn't an aggregate (which in your original example is the case with C++14, but not C++17). It never applies to `A` because `A` has a user-provided default constructor and therefore 9.1.1 already applies to it. The effect of 9.1.1 is _only_ the constructor call, the effect of 9.1.2. is (recursive) zero-initialization, followed by constructor call.

Comment: *Had you initialized with parentheses, e.g. B b = B(); then the whole B object would have been value-initialized which would have implied zero-initialization of all of B*. It looks like both GCC and Clang disagree with that if check in a constant expression:  https://godbolt.org/z/51PdqfYdf

Comment: @Fedor Looks like a bug in both then. Before C++20 all members had to be explicitly initialized in a constant expression. Maybe the compilers therefore implemented it differently from the runtime case and didn't update it properly when the restriction was lifted. However GCC at least doesn't perform the zero-initialization even at runtime. This has already been reported, e.g. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=111771.

Comment: Clang issue reported: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/69890

Answer (score 0):

To me, 9.1.1 clearly applies here, because we have "default constructor that is user-provided" in the struct A. Behavior of clang is therefore strictly conforming and behavior of GCC is at least not non-conforming. I.e. although GCC actually does zero-init, you must not rely on that.

Comment: `T` in this case is `B`, not `A`.  `B` does not have a user provided default constructor

Comment: No, because we talk about member "x", which is introduced within "A", so constructor of "A" is responsible for its initialization. B inherits A and normally, constructor of B (even implicitly generated one) first calls constructor of A, which should initialize "x". Of course, this call can be optimized & inlined by a compiler.

Comment: @ivan.ukr The object whose construction begins the process is `B`, not `A`. If it is indeed zero-initialized - all its parents are too, regardless of their ctors , as specified in (6.2).

Comment: No, 6.2 is sub-item of 6, which only explains how "zero-initialization" itself is performed. It does not say when zero-initialization is applied. There is no such thing in C++ as "regardless of their ctors" - if you have ctor, it MUST be used. So in this case B has implicitly generated default ctor, which in the first place calls A's ctor (this call may be inlined & further optimized, as I said before), and then initializes members introduced B, which are supposed to be initialized from initializer-list, which is empty, which results zero-initialization for "y".

Comment: @ivan.ukr This was surprising to me too, but it turns out that there *is* in fact such a thing in C++ as "regardless of their ctors".   As the standard wording above states,  *if* zero-init is in effect - parent ctors are not considered. "(6.2) if T is a ... non-union class type, ..., each non-virtual base class subobject, ... is zero-initialized".

Comment: @OfekShilon In that case (typically) a default constructor is still called afterwards though, just to make sure that my answer isn't misleading. That's implied by "_then the object is default-initialized_". However in the case of (9.1.2) it is technically possible that a trivial default constructor isn't called (but it wouldn't do anything anyway). But there is also aggregate initialization which doesn't use the implicit (or defaulted before C++20) default constructor even though it exists.

Comment: @user17732522 Indeed!  Adding output from `A::A()` demonstrates it perfectly: https://godbolt.org/z/qs967sTzn.   @ivan.ukr , @HolyBlackCat  - I stand corrected, I misunderstood the answer